# Метафункция, для определения существования специализации функтора для данного в шаблоне типа

Tags: c++, c++11, шаблоны-с++, метапрограммирование

Метафункция принимает в шаблоне проверяемый тип. Если оператор скобок определен у Method<данный_тип>, то метафункция должна вернуть true. Иначе false.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

template<typename T>
struct Method {};

template<>
struct Method<int> {
    int operator()() { return 1; }
};

template<class T>
struct is_brackets_op_defined {
  static void Check(...);

  template<typename C>
  static decltype(Method<C>::operator()) Check(const C&);

  using type = decltype(Check(
    std::declval< Method<T> >()  
  ));

  constexpr static bool value =  
    !std::is_same<void, type>();
};

int main() {
    std::cout << is_brackets_op_defined<float>::value << std::endl;
}
```

Моя реализация всегда возвращает false, даже если специализация существует (здесь для int)

```
std::cout << is_brackets_op_defined<float>::value // false
std::cout << is_brackets_op_defined<int  >::value // false
```

Comment: Я не сильно разбираюсь в стандарте, но вполне возможно, что первая функция "более сильная" чем шаблонная функция. Компилятор всегда ленивый. Выбирает те функции, где надо меньше всего выводить типы, так что скорее всего постоянно используется только 1 функция. Попробуйте потестировать.

Comment: Раздел [viable functions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution)

Comment: Не уверен, почему этот вариант не работает, но в качестве более простой альтернативы можно попробовать `std::experimental::is_detected`.

Comment: Писал схожую метафункцию для немного другой ситуации (проверялось наличие метода в типе), все работало. Читал где-то, что функции с переменным числом аргументом менее приоритетны

Comment: std::experimental::is_detected кажется очень даже хорошим и удобным вариантом, но задание из части университетского курса. Смысл его как раз в реализации "ручками". Так это был бы замечательный вариант

Comment: `decltype(Method<C>::operator())` - это может быть корректным только при наличии в классе `Method<C>` *статического* члена `operator()`. Но `operator()` не может быть статическим. И в качестве типа возвращаемого значения функции это не допустимо в любом случае, ибо это будет типом "функция".

Comment: @Ant, штука в том, что даже если это исправить на корректное выражение (`decltype(&Method<C>::operator())`), всё равно не рассматривается компилятором как viable. Не понимаю почему.

Comment: @ixSci: Закомментируйте `void` версию и по сообщению компилятора сразу станет ясно в чем ошибка. У автора делается проверка на наличие `operator ()` в `Method<Method<T>>`. В проверялке он умудрился **два раза** "завернуть" все в шаблон `Method`. Вот так работает: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3058a2ba45ef597a

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Отлаживать метапрограммы не самое простое знятие, но мы все же попробуем.

Для начала уберем использование `is_brackets_op_defined<float>` и объявление `static void Check(...);`. Это поможет нам увидеь чем-же компилятору не понравилась перегруженная версия `Check`([код](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/39198d305036d248)).

> `main.cpp:19:30: error: no matching function for call to
>   'is_brackets_op_defined<int>::Check(Method<int>)'
>   main.cpp:17:42: note: candidate: 'template<class C> static decltype (Method<C>::operator()) is_brackets_op_defined<T>::Check(const C&) [with C = C; T = int]'
>   main.cpp:17:42: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
>   main.cpp: In substitution of 'template<class C> static decltype (Method<T>::operator()) is_brackets_op_defined<int>::Check<C>(const C&) [with C = Method<int>]':`

Ну вот, в качестве `C` в функцию `Check` приходит `Method<int>`. Очевидно что в таком контексте кострукция `Method<C>::operator()` дает ошибку компиляции и для `int`, и для `float`. И согласно SFINAE компилятор отбрасывает эту перегрузку.

Надо как-то изменить это вражение так, чтобы оно разворачивалось в какой-то тип для `int` и давало substitution failed для `float`. На мой взгляд `&C::operator()` будет в самый раз([код](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1df5481d1d0204db)).

---

В принципе на этом можно остановиться, но не могу не предложить чуточку упростить код. В качестве возвращаемых значений можно использовать `std::true_type` и `std::false_type` это позволит выкинуть использование `std::is_same`.

---

**UPD.** Вопрос в комментарии навел на мысль о втором улучшении. Вместо `const C&` можно использовать `const C*`. Это позволит избавится от `std::declval`, который, по какой-то причине, создает ошибку компиляции с incomplete type под GCC.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

template<typename T>
struct Method;

template<>
struct Method<int> {
    int operator()() { return 1; }
};

template<class T>
struct is_brackets_op_defined {
  static std::false_type Check(...);

  template<typename C, class = decltype(&C::operator())>
  static std::true_type Check(const C*);

  using type = decltype(Check(static_cast<Method<T>*>(nullptr)));

  constexpr static bool value = type();
};

int main() {
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << is_brackets_op_defined<float>::value << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << is_brackets_op_defined<int>::value << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Большое спасибо. Теперь буду знать, как в следующий раз искать ошибку. Ваш ответ окончательно внес ясность, в чем я именно ошибался

Comment: @JekyllHyde, тогда примите этот ответ, а с моего галку снимите. Этот ответ лучше.

Comment: @ixSci, по мне  неоднозначно чей ответ лучше, поскольку ваш ответ дает вариант правильного решения

Comment: @ARHovsepyan, мой лишь частично отвечает на вопрос «почему не работает?» и предлагает альтернативное решение. Этот ответ более предметный и помогает автору лучше понять ошибку.

Comment: @ixSci, я с вами согласен и высоко ценю вашу честность, но  мне понравился ваш ответ, хотя это не значит, что  этот ответ меньше понравился

Comment: @yrHeTaTeJlb, а что делать в том случае, если базовая структура будет incomplete типом? Т.е.
`template<typename T>
struct Method;`

Comment: @JekyllHyde, обновил ответ

Comment: @yrHeTaTeJlb, спасибо вам за все

Comment: Между указателем и ссылкой нет разницы, в части incomplete type

Comment: @ixSci, однако компилятор в упор отказывается работать для случаев, когда тип не принадлежит специализации. Я вам уже показывал пример, но чтобы вы не искали, повторюсь http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8a8ae67fd91202a1

Comment: @ixSci, не уверен в чем именно проблема. `std::declval` можно использовать только в [unevaluated expressions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/expressions#Unevaluated_expressions). Возможно, gcc считает что это не тот случай. Clang и MSVC копилируют этот код нормально.

Comment: Там штука в эллипсах, т.е. declval дал на выходе ссылку, которую, при выборе эллипса нужно копировать, а ссылка не копируется, но копируется объект по ссылке. Но всё это происходит в unevaluated context. Поэтому и не ясно, правильно ли тут поступает gcc или нет. Надо будет шерстить стандарт.

Answer (score 6):

Ответа почему не работает Ваш код у меня нет, но есть то, что заставит его работать:

```
template<typename C>
static decltype(std::declval<C>().operator()()) Check(const C&);
```

В Вашем коде есть очевидная проблема: `Method<C>::operator()` не корректный C++, т.к. это функция-член с которой ничего не делается. А её нужно либо вызывать, либо брать её адрес.

Comment: Большое спасибо за пояснение с:

Comment: @JekyllHyde, у меня, кстати, есть [статья](http://scrutator.me/post/2017/04/10/has_function_metaprogramming.aspx) на эту тему. Можете ознакомиться, там есть обобщённый пример.

Comment: "В Вашем коде есть очевидная проблема: Method<C>::operator() не корректный C++...". Вы правы, и вы указали на ошибку, из за чего и не работает код.

Comment: @ARHovsepyan, я благодарен всем отвечающим и считаю их ответы полезными. В случае с ответом выше мне понравилось, что автор дополнительно указал, как производить отладку

Comment: @ixSci, можете подсказать, как быть в том случае, если тело базовой структуры не описано? Т.е.
`template<typename T> struct Method;`

Comment: @Jekyll Hyde, и вам спасибо за хороший вопрос. Ведь ответы полезны не только вам, но и нам_читающим.  Не могу не согласится с вами, все зависит от того, что лично вам полезней.  Один ответ полезней тем, что вы указали, а другой тем, что исправляет ошибку, не вносив изменений в классах и заодно напоминает, что без обьекта нельзя вызывать нестатический метод класса... Но это  мнение непрофессионала(имею ввиду себя)

Comment: @JekyllHyde, мой вариант не требует определения базового случая. Т.е. будет работать и для incomplete.

Comment: @ixSci, возможно, я что-то делаю не так? http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8a8ae67fd91202a1

Comment: @JekyllHyde, это либо баг GCC, либо баг в MSVC & Clang. Где баг — надо разбираться.

Comment: @ixSci, понял. В любом случае, спасибо вам. Воспользуюсь обходом бага, что предложил пользователь товарищ yrHeTaTeJlb

Comment: @ixSci, впервые пишу в русскоязычный stackoverflow. Рад, что тут такое приятное комьюнити с:

Answer (score 0):

Можно вот так. Заметьте, что вспомогательная функция тоже является шаблоном:

```
#include <iostream>

template<class T> struct
is_brackets_op_defined
{
    private: template<typename C> static
    char ( & Check(...) )[1];

    private: template<typename C> static
    char ( & Check(decltype(&C::operator ())) )[2];

    public: static constexpr bool value{2 == sizeof(Check<T>(nullptr))};
};

struct ClassWith
{
    void operator ()() {}
};

struct ClassWithout
{
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << is_brackets_op_defined<float>::value << std::endl;
    std::cout << is_brackets_op_defined<ClassWith>::value << std::endl;
    std::cout << is_brackets_op_defined<ClassWithout>::value << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

[online compiler](https://wandbox.org/permlink/oOcNOof9Q26y5Glo)

Comment: Получается, что вы изменили только возвращаемый тип?

Comment: Да, мне необходимо было узнать не то, что в типе есть оператор скобок, а то, что структура с шаблоном этого типа имеет этот оператор. Мне уже дали ответ выше, но спасибо вам за ответ с:

Comment: @JekyllHyde Нет, отчего же. Предложенный вариант более обобщенный и может проверять наличие оператора у любого типа, а не только у специализации конкретного шаблона.